# Tried to limit the display of characters using length, substring(0, 10)`, but getting error

Tags: reactjs

In a react web app I have tried to limit the display of characters using `length` and `substring(0, 10)`, but getting below error: Could someone please share some advise to fix the issue ?
Error details:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at admin.js:153:1
at Array.map ()
at Admin (admin.js:148:1)

```
                 <div className='row'>
                        <div className='editBlogSection'>
                            {
                                blogList.map(({ id, blogdetails, tags, count }) => (
                                    <div className='row'>
                                        <a key={id} href="" className='blogitems'>
                                            <pre><span>{tags}</span> {blogdetails.length > 10 ? blogdetails.substring(0, 10) + '...' : blogdetails}<span>{count}</span></pre>
                                        </a>
                                        <div className='blogitems edit'>
                                            <button>Edit</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='blogitems delete'>
                                            <button onClick={() => handleBlogDelete(id)}>Delete</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You need to check if the value exists. Try `!!blogdetails && blogdetails.length`

Comment: Thank very much that actually fixed the issue, do we need that `!!` before blogdetails  ?

Comment: `!!` converts  value to boolean. If you use it directly, it will work but as a convention, I prefer using `!!` as its clearer.